# how to insert table stucture inside other table structure in other database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have two design tables:
old table:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ProductId]
      ,[ProductLanguageId]
      ,[ProductVariantId]
      ,[ProductDefaultShopId]
      ,[ProductNumber]
      ,[ProductName]
      ,[ProductShortDescription]
      ,[ProductLongDescription]
      ,[ProductImageSmall]
      ,[ProductImageMedium]
      ,[ProductImageLarge]
      ,[ProductLink1]
      ,[ProductLink2]
      ,[ProductPrice]
      ,[ProductStock]
      ,[ProductStockGroupId]
      ,[ProductWeight]
      ,[ProductVolume]
      ,[ProductVatGrpId]
      ,[ProductManufacturerId]
      ,[ProductActive]
      ,[ProductPeriodId]
      ,[ProductCreated]
      ,[ProductUpdated]
      ,[ProductCustomFieldsXml]
      ,[ProductType]
      ,[ProductPriceType]
      ,[ProductPriceCounter]
      ,[ProductVariantCounter]
      ,[ProductVariantProdCounter]
      ,[ProductVariantGroupCounter]
      ,[ProductRelatedCounter]
      ,[ProductUnitCounter]
      ,[ProductDefaultUnitId]
      ,[ProductDefaultVariantComboId]
      ,[ProductPriceMatrixUnit]
      ,[ProductPriceMatrixVariant]
      ,[ProductPriceMatrixPeriod]
      ,[ProductPriceMatrixMultiplePrices]
      ,[ProductPriceMatrixQuantitySpecification]
      ,[ProductMetaTitle]
      ,[ProductMetaKeywords]
      ,[ProductMetaDescription]
      ,[ProductMetaUrl]
      ,[ProductCategoryFieldValues]
      ,[ProductOptimizedFor]
      ,[ProductCommentcount]
      ,[ProductRating]
      ,[ProductCost]
      ,[ProductAutoId]
      ,[ProductMetaCanonical]
      ,[ProductExcludeFromIndex]
      ,[ProductExcludeFromCustomizedUrls]
      ,[ProductExcludeFromAllProducts]
      ,[ItemCode]
      ,[TaxCode]
      ,[ProductPoints]
  FROM [verploegenbalie].[dbo].[EcomProducts
```

New table:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ProductID]
      ,[ProductLanguageID]
      ,[ProductVariantID]
      ,[ProductDefaultShopID]
      ,[ProductNumber]
      ,[ProductName]
      ,[ProductShortDescription]
      ,[ProductLongDescription]
      ,[ProductImageSmall]
      ,[ProductImageMedium]
      ,[ProductImageLarge]
      ,[ProductLink1]
      ,[ProductLink2]
      ,[ProductPrice]
      ,[ProductStock]
      ,[ProductStockGroupID]
      ,[ProductWeight]
      ,[ProductVolume]
      ,[ProductVatGrpID]
      ,[ProductManufacturerID]
      ,[ProductActive]
      ,[ProductPeriodID]
      ,[ProductCreated]
      ,[ProductUpdated]
      ,[ProductCustomFieldsXml]
      ,[ProductType]
      ,[ProductPriceType]
      ,[ProductPriceCounter]
      ,[ProductVariantCounter]
      ,[ProductVariantProdCounter]
      ,[ProductVariantGroupCounter]
      ,[ProductRelatedCounter]
      ,[ProductUnitCounter]
      ,[ProductDefaultUnitID]
      ,[ProductDefaultVariantComboID]
      ,[ProductPriceMatrixUnit]
      ,[ProductPriceMatrixVariant]
      ,[ProductPriceMatrixPeriod]
      ,[ProductPriceMatrixMultiplePrices]
      ,[ProductPriceMatrixQuantitySpecification]
      ,[producent]
      ,[ProductMetaTitle]
      ,[ProductMetaKeywords]
      ,[ProductMetaDescription]
      ,[ProductMetaUrl]
      ,[ProductOptimizedFor]
      ,[ProductCommentcount]
      ,[ProductRating]
      ,[ProductCost]
      ,[ProductAutoID]
      ,[Sale]
      ,[OrderArticle]
      ,[DaySupplier]
      ,[AllowReturn]
      ,[ExtraProductInformation]
      ,[SupplierLink]
      ,[Brand]
      ,[SupplierArticleNumber]
      ,[TresholdRotterdam]
      ,[TresholdAmsterdam]
      ,[StockRotterdam]
      ,[StockAmsterdam]
      ,[StockZoetermeer]
      ,[TresholdZoetermeer]
      ,[Substitute]
      ,[ProductMetaCanonical]
      ,[ProductExcludeFromIndex]
      ,[ProductExcludeFromCustomizedUrls]
      ,[ProductExcludeFromAllProducts]
      ,[Specificaties]
      ,[CrossReference]
      ,[StockDenhaagLoosduinseweg]
      ,[TresholdDenhaagLoosduinseweg]
      ,[StockDenhaagBinckhorst]
      ,[TresholdDenhaagBinckhorst]
      ,[CanOrderPartialArticle]
      ,[ProductPoints]
  FROM [Dynamicweb-Verploegen-Test_new].[dbo].[EcomProducts]
```

But now I want the structure of the old table in the new table.Because in the new table there are fields that are not in the old tbale. But also the old talble is in database:Dynamicweb-Verploegen-Test_new

and the old table is in database: verploegenbalie

But how to update the old table from the new table?

Thank you

I ask this question, because maybe there are other ways to realize it. But again somebody gives me negative points?? Realy for what?? I am very clear in my question.

Comment: Am I correct that you want to add new columns to the first table so it has the same structure as the second table? Could you highlight what the differences are between the two tables? And did you also need to insert any data?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. ONly the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [ALTER TABLE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) syntax, which allows you to add new columns to an existing table. The new columns will be added to the end of the table.

```
ALTER TABLE verploegenbalie
ADD Column1 DataType,
    Column2 DataType,
    etc.
```

Comment: Thank you. Ofcourse I know that. But maybe there was a other way to do it? That' s is why I ask it.

Comment: You can also right click the table, go into the Design menu and manually add the columns. Or, if you want to compare the two table structures you can get the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html) for both tables and join them to each other.